# How to grant permissions for a file automatically?

Tags: permissions

When I try to run a python file, say `hello.py`, it prompts

```
bash: ./hello.py: Permission denied
```

so I need to

```
chmod u+x hello.py
```

before I run it.

Is it possible to automatically grant access to all python file as soon as they are created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple script like this,

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 2 ]
then
    chmod +x $(pwd)/$1
    $(pwd)/$1
else
    chmod +x $(pwd)/$1
    $(pwd)/$1 $2
fi
```

Save the above script as `runpy.sh`, keep it in `PATH` (you can keep it in `~/bin`)

Give it execution permission from terminal,

```
chmod +x ~/bin/runpy.sh
```

**Usage**

- To run `hello.py` without changing its permission run in terminal,

```
runpy.sh hello.py
```

- In case if you want to use anything at the argument of the python program, give the arguments inside `" "` like,

```
runpy.sh hello.py "-option arg1 arg2 agr3"
```

It should do the trick. But don't forget to use the shebang line in python (`.py`) file,

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: @Zhang Yifan Plz take a look at the script, I improved it so that you can use argument also.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. You have to chmod these files yourself. If you have a programmable editor (such as vim or emacs), you can write a plugin that automatically does this when writing a file whose name ends with .py.